# Loading tree nodes only when expanding nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview, kentico

I have a asp.net tree view control, which loads tree data on page load. Code given below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DocEng.TreeProvider cmsTree = new DocEng.TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
                var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");
                DocEng.TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
                IEnumerable<DocEng.TreeNode> TreeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<DocEng.TreeNode>();
                foreach (var tree in TreeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeLevel == 0))
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ParenTreeNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
                    ParenTreeNode.Text = tree.NodeID.ToString() + ". " + SiteContext.CurrentSiteName;
                    ParenTreeNode.Value = tree.NodeID.ToString();
                    AddNodes(ParenTreeNode);
                    tvContentTree.Nodes.Add(ParenTreeNode);
                }
            }
        }


  /// <summary>
        /// Adding child for the parent 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="TreeNode"></param>
        private void AddNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode TreeNode)
        {
            DocEng.TreeProvider cmsTree = new DocEng.TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
            var node = cmsTree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/", "en-US");
            DocEng.TreeNodeCollection myChildren = node.AllChildren;
            IEnumerable<DocEng.TreeNode> childTreeNodes = myChildren.AsEnumerable<DocEng.TreeNode>();
            foreach (var childTree in childTreeNodes.Where(x => x.NodeParentID == Convert.ToInt32(TreeNode.Value)))
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode ChildNode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode();
                ChildNode.Text = childTree.NodeID.ToString() + ". " + childTree.DocumentName.ToString();
                ChildNode.Value = childTree.NodeID.ToString();
                TreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);
                AddNodes(ChildNode);
                if (childTree.NodeLevel == 1)
                    ChildNode.Collapse();
            }
        }
```

I need to rewrite this code, to load the data only when we expand the nodes. Moreover, while we expand, data should only populated to the clicked node and its children till the end.

Comment: Not sure what the question here is...Have you tried to rewrite the code yourself? You'll have to use the [`TreeNodeExpanded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodeexpanded(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You can get some inspiration by looking at the CMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\ContentTree.ascx control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Get only first level of nodes on Page-Load and foreach node add one empty child node, just to make it expandable.

Then after expanding remove this child node and populate it with normal children.